# Button Longpress / Standard Touch difference

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, touch, long-press

I'm having two controls, one EditText and a layout that holds buttons. The layout acts like a suggestion box, that has its visibility toggled as soon as the edittext receives focus.

When I focus the edittext, the box becomes visible. Now when I click one of its buttons, the edittext loses the focus and therefore toggles the visibility to "Gone" on my suggestion box.
When I do a longpress on any of the buttons, the focus is not lost on the edittext.

How can I achieve the long press behaviour on the buttons, with a standard touch? Meaning how can I make the edittext not lose the focus by clicking on the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

> Meaning how can I make the edittext not lose the focus by clicking on
>   the buttons.

You have to implement `OnFocusChangeListener` for achieve this, have look.

```
ediitext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
        {
            ediitext.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    });
```

Comment: But this would always make my edittext be focused when trying to unfocus it. Do you know what is happening when I longpress and why the longpress gives the desired result?

Comment: did you means on button long press you getting focus on edittext ?

Comment: No, i mean that longpress does not make my edittext lose the focus, but standard press does. but i've found a solution, i will share it, when i find time to do so

Comment: it is basically to return true at the start of the ontouch of the button that was clicked. So no focus changes will happen.

Comment: Damn it seems not to work anymore, i thought it worked, but apparently it does not omg.............